# How to add subdomain to Azure WebSite via API

Tags: c#, azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, hostname

My website is hosted as Azure WebSite and I need to allow users create their own subdomains.
I already implemented this on local machine using DNS and CNAME option, but I can't do it in Azure. When I try to add Azure host name for the site I receive error that hostname must ends with '**.azurewebsites.net**'.

Here is my code:

```
var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureSubscriptionId"],
                    new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath, "{certificate}"), "{password}")));

var configuration = client.WebSites.Get(webSpaceName, webSiteName, new WebSiteGetParameters());

if (configuration.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    throw new Exception("AzureGet: " + subdomain);

configuration.WebSite.HostNames.Add(hostName);
var response = client.WebSites.Update(webSpaceName, webSiteName, new WebSiteUpdateParameters());
```

Is there any other methods to add  custom HostName like '**sub.mydomain.net**'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a wildcard custom domain name for your website, and then check the hostname in your application code by inspecting the headers (host or X-Forwarded-Host) of the incoming request.

i.e. your domain name would point *.mydomain.net to your web app, and then your DB keeps track of the user registered domains, and then your web app does the routing.